# How to display progress panel in System Tray with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, onedrive, system-tray

I'm developing an app that's going to run in the background with .NET Framework and I want to show progress. Something like in the [OneDrive desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dacyL.jpg).

I've tried a notifyIcon with ShowBalloonTip but I want something more permanent and if possible with a loading bar (if not possible, I can do with just text).

Comment: use an object of NotifyIcon and change its Text property on a Timer Elapsed event.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I'm looking for something like the OneDrive/Dropbox UI or the battery panel that displays the battery percentage and settings when the icon is clicked. I'm interested in the UI Panel/Menu, not so much on the info part, I've already got that covered.

Comment: Design a WinForms window and show/hide it in that corner (hooked to NotifyIcon events).

Comment: I guess that's as close as I'm going to get. I've used "this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;" to make it more similar to the pop-up panels. Thank you.